# Custom iOS transition similar to UIScrollView paging (like what Luminosity does for their transitions)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm after a straightforward custom push transition where the new view controller "pushes" the current view controller off to the left and replaces it. Pretty much what UIScrollView does when paging is turned on...but for view controller transitions.

Luminosity does this for all (or most) of their transitions: https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/lumosity-mobile/id577232024?mt=8

Given the simplicity of this transition, I'd have thought a simple google search would find an example and source code, but all I can find are exotic transitions (flip, explode, swing etc. etc. etc.)

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be fantastic. I assume the transition code is straightforward, so my next step is to actually learn how custom transitions work and build it myself.

NB: the transition I describe is different to the default ios push transition which does a bunch of funky fading and sliding: http://watchingapple.com/2009/11/a-closer-look-at-iphone-transition-animations/

Comment: if the question is about how to actually perform the transition, then add the fromViewController.view to the transitionContainer, add the toViewController.view to it (set its frame to be on the right of the fromViewController.view), perform an animation that shifts both one viewWidth to the left and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you found your answer by now.  But for anyone else that finds this question...

There is a very good drop in library on github by Colin Eberhardt called VCTransitionsLibrary that has a number of cool ios 7+ transitions. I think the 'pan' transition matches the questioners requirements perfectly:

https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/VCTransitionsLibrary/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Almost! It doesn't pan the navigation bar. But that can be easily solved by building a pseudo-navigation bar from a UIView, UILabel and UIButtons. Thanks @DEzra